# Programmatically adding multiple subviews with constraints throws exception

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, ios10

## Environment

- Xcode-8
- Swift-3
- iOS-10

## Intent

  The germain intent is to get three subviews added to the main view, such that they appear sequentially adjacent starting from the top of the screen.
  There's more to the ultimate intent, but this is where I'm currently stuck.

## Working Code

  If I'm just adding a single subview, it works with the following code (
  *slightly abridged, line numbers added for reference*
  ):

```
01: class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {
02:    var textMatte: UIView!

03:    override func viewDidLoad() {
04:        super.viewDidLoad()
05:        setupTextfieldMatte(inView: view)
06:    }

07:    func setupTextfieldMatte(inView: UIView) {
08:        textMatte = UIView()
09:        textMatte.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
10:        textMatte.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
11:        inView.addSubview(textMatte)
12:        let tmGuide = textMatte.layoutMarginsGuide
13:        let inGuide = inView.layoutMarginsGuide
14:        tmGuide.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: inGuide.topAnchor, constant: 40).isActive = true
15:        tmGuide.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: inGuide.leadingAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
16:        tmGuide.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: inGuide.trailingAnchor, constant: -20).isActive = true
17:        tmGuide.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40).isActive = true
18:    }
19:    //... other code ...
20: }
```

## Broken Code

  I wanted to break-up the
  *creation*
  step from the
  *constraint*
  step, in order to do "batch" processing (and because there's more that needs to happen, as eventually
  *these*
  subviews will also have their own subviews...). Added relative line numbers for ease of further description and (hopefully) answers from you folks:

```
01: class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {
02:     var mattes = [UIView()]

03:     override func viewDidLoad() {
04:         super.viewDidLoad()
05:         for (index, title) in ["A", "B", "C"].enumerated() { // genericized for posting
06:            let v = createView(idx: index)
07:             mattes.append(v)
08:             view.addSubview(v)
09:         }
10:         _ = mattes.popLast() //from testing/debugging found that there was an extraneous entry in the array
11:         addViewAnnotations(views: mattes, inView: self.view)
12:     }

13:     func createView(idx: Int) -> UIView {
14:         let v = UIView()
15:         v.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
16:         v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
17:         v.tag = idx
18:         return v
19:     }

20:     func addViewAnnotations(views: [UIView], inView: UIView) {
21:         let inGuide = inView.layoutMarginsGuide
22:         for (index, v) in views.enumerated() {
23:             let myGuide = v.layoutMarginsGuide
24:             if index == 0 {
25:                 myGuide.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: inGuide.topAnchor, constant: 40).isActive = true
***                 //^^^ libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
26:             }
27:             else {
28:                 myGuide.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: views[index-1].layoutMarginsGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
29:             }
30:             myGuide.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: inGuide.leadingAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
31:             myGuide.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: inGuide.trailingAnchor, constant: -20).isActive = true
32:             myGuide.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40).isActive = true
33:         }
34:     }
35:     //... other code ...
36: }
```

  The error occurs on line 25 (error message in comment below that line), verified with
  `print`
  statements above and below the line.
  There's no additional error/debugging information that I can see
  I had expected that it
  *might*
  break on line 28, but 25 (in the "broken code") is identical to line 14 (in the working code)
  **Note:**
  If I put a
  `try`
  in from of the line, Xcode tells me: "No calls to throwing functions occur within 'try' expression"

I have a feeling that this is one of those stupid oversights that crop up so often when modifying code, but I just cannot seem to spot the source of the problem - so I'm hoping one of you can.

## UPDATE 2016-10-16

  Based on my modification as described in the first comment I added, I played around with the code a bit more and found that the problem occurs only when trying to make [what is now] the last constraint
  *active*
  :

```
001:    override func viewDidLoad() {
002:        super.viewDidLoad()

003:        for (index, title) in ["Small Blind", "Big Blind", "Ante"].enumerated() {
004:            let v = createView(idx: index)
005:            mattes.append(v)
006:            view.addSubview(v)
007:            let myGuide = v.layoutMarginsGuide
008:            let inGuide = view.layoutMarginsGuide
009:            myGuide.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: inGuide.leadingAnchor, constant: 20 ).isActive = true
010:            myGuide.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: inGuide.trailingAnchor, constant: -20).isActive = true
011:            myGuide.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40).isActive = true
012:            if index == 0 {
013:                myGuide.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: inGuide.topAnchor, constant: 40).isActive = true
014:            }
015:            else {
016:                let x = myGuide.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: mattes[index-1].bottomAnchor, constant: 10)
017:                x.isActive = true
                    //^^^ libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
018:            }
019:        }
020:    }
```

  All the other constraints have no issues. It doesn't seem to matter if I use:
  - `mattes[index-1].bottomAnchor`
  - `mattes[index-1].layoutMarginsGuide.bottomAnchor`
  The first one evaluates to
  `<NSLayoutYAxisAnchor:0x174076540 "UIView:0x100b0d380.bottom">`
  , the second to
  `<NSLayoutYAxisAnchor:0x174076c00 "UILayoutGuide:0x174191e00'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide'.bottom">`
  (
  *if that matters?*
  )
  If I comment out line 017, the code runs, but while the first rectangle is in the correct location, the remaining two are not - they're flush against the top of the screen instead of below the top indicators.
  So - perhaps there's a better way to set them up?

Comment: Interestingly, if I move the constraint code (lines 21, 23-32) into the `viewDidLoad` function (after line 8), adjusting for the changes in the looping - it gets past what was line 25 and *does* break [right now] on what was line 28... continuing to plod around...

Comment: See **UPDATE 2016-10-16** in posting, in reference to previous comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it was a combination of things that was causing the problem, but first let me present the working code and a couple of screen shots

```
001: class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {
002:     var textfields: [UITextField] = []
003:     var labels:     [UILabel]     = []
004:     var mattes:     [UIView]      = []

005:     override func viewDidLoad() {
006:         super.viewDidLoad()

007:         view.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
008:         for title in ["A", "B", "C"] {
009:             let matte     = setupMatte(inView: view)
010:             let textfield = setupTextfield(inView: view, title: title)
011:             let label     = setupLabel(inView: view, title: title)
012:             mattes.append(matte)
013:             textfields.append(textfield)
014:             labels.append(label)
015:         }
016:         addConstraints(inView: view) // could probably leave off parameter, but for now...
017:     }

018:     func setupMatte(inView: UIView) -> UIView {
019:         let matte = UIView()

             //...various view attribute configurations...
020:         matte.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
021:         inView.addSubview(matte)
022:         return matte
023:     }

024:     func setupTextfield(inView: UIView, title: String) -> UITextField {
025:         let textfield = UITextField()

             //...various textfield attribute configurations...
026:         textfield.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
027:         inView.addSubview(textfield)
028:         return textfield
029:     }

030:     func setupLabel(inView: UIView, title: String) -> UILabel {
031:         let label = UILabel()

             //...various label attribute configurations...
032:         label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
033:         inView.addSubview(label)
034:         return label
035:     }

036:     func addConstraints(inView: UIView) {
037:         for (index, matte) in mattes.enumerated() {
038:             let textfield = textfields[index]
039:             let label     = labels[index]

040:             matte.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: inView.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
041:             matte.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: inView.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
042:             matte.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true

043:             label.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: matte.leadingAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
044:             label.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 150).isActive = true

045:             textfield.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: label.trailingAnchor, constant: 5).isActive = true
046:             textfield.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: matte.trailingAnchor, constant: -20).isActive = true

047:             if index == 0 {
048:                 matte.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: inView.topAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
049:             }
050:             else {
051:                 matte.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: mattes[index - 1].bottomAnchor, constant: 5).isActive = true
052:             }

053:             textfield.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: matte.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
054:             label.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: textfield.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
055:         }
056:     }
         //... other code ...
057: }
```

[image]

Interestingly, while the image from the simulator correctly handles landscape mode, when I run it on my iPhone 6s - it doesn't rotate when I hold the phone in landscape mode - but I'm not too worried about that at this time, since the app I'm working on is only intended for portrait mode.

Now, the pieces that I think made a significant difference from my original code:
(***Note:*** I don't know why, but for some reason I originally named the function for handling constraints "Annotations", this was fixed in my current working code)

---

**BROKEN :** `var mattes = [UIView()]`
**WORKING:** `var mattes: [UIView] = []`

I think the above may have been a significant difference

---

**BROKEN :** `viewDidLoad` function looped:

- Created sub-view
- Appended sub-view to `mattes` array
- Called `view.addSubview(v)`
- *After loop:*
- Popped off last element of `mattes` array
- Added annotations

**WORKING:** `viewDidLoad` function looped:

- Created sub-view (`matte`)

  - The creation process called `inView.addSubview(matte)` (where `inView` is the same as `view` or `self.view`)
- Appended sub-view to `mattes` array
- *After loop:*
- Added annotations

I think the difference in how `mattes` was defined eliminated the need to pop off the last (or any) element in the array before going to add the constraints

---

**BROKEN :** in `addViewAnnotations` I made constraints using the `layoutMarginGuide` of both the sub-view *and* [parent] view

```
v.layoutMarginGuide.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.layoutMarginGuide.topAnchor, constant: 40).isActive = true
```

**WORKING:** in `addConstraints` I made the constraints directly from the sub-view *and* [parent] view

```
matte.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
```

(*Thanks to **Jerry** for pointing this out, I didn't understand the distinction and I don't think I fully fixed my code when I did my "UPDATE"*)

The above was probably the *most* significant difference

Answer (score 0):

What is the description of the exception?  Be sure to add views to their superview (in the same view hierarchy) before adding the constraints. You can't create constraints between views that aren't both in the same hierarchy.

In your update, you're using `index-1` as an index into the `mattes` array, that may be the cause of the exception the first time around.

I don't know if this is contributing to issues, but I don't create constraints from one view's layoutMarginsGuide to a superview's layoutMarginsGuide.  Think of that guide as for the view and it's subviews.  So the constraints would be from the subview itself (not its margin) to the superview's layoutMarginsGuide.

Comment: ***... description of the exception?*** `libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException` that's it.
***... add views to superview (same view hierarchy) before adding constraints. You can't create constraints between views [not] in same hierarchy.*** "Broken Code" lines 05-11 I: (a) create subview, (b) add subview to mattes array, (c) add subview *as* subview to primary view - all before constraints.  If "A" has two subviews "A1" and "A2" - can constraints exist between "A1" and "A2"?


(more to come, limited by character count, and time between postings)

Comment: ***In your update, you're using index-1 as an index into the mattes array, that may be the cause of the exception the first time around.***
The if/else clause should ensure first time through is *not* making constraints between two "mattes"

(*sorry, cannot figure out how to properly format comments, especially within character-count limitations*)

Comment: ***... don't constrain from view's layoutMarginsGuide to superview's layoutMarginsGuide. ... constraints [are] from subview (not its margin) to superview's layoutMarginsGuide.***
I've tried different combinations (a la "UPDATE" code):  
v.layoutMarginsGuide.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: mattes[index-1].layoutMarginsGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: 10)`  
v.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: mattes[index-1].layoutMarginsGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: 10)`  
v.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: mattes[index-1].bottomAnchor, constant: 10)`  
For all, on `x.isActive = true`, it died with same exception.

Comment: You're right about the `if` before `index-1`, my bad.  Deciphering the exception is going to be the key to solving this.  Although the line you pasted should be the last line in the console when the exception is thrown, above that you should see a stack trace, but above the line that says "First throw call stack", you should see the type of exception and a description of what was thrown.  That will tell you the cause for the error.

Comment: (I thought I responded to this yesterday...) What you (Jerry) are describing regarding exception call stacks is - normally - valid, but in this case, there is nothing but the one line I indicated.  Having dug around a bit on the web, it seems that this type of error, which is generated from Objective-C code, is "known" to not provide useful error-handling within Swift.

Comment: If you'll post a sample on github or somewhere, I'll take a look.

Comment: I think I figured it out - or at least I got it working - will post details as "answer" shortly.